# Joined reports error: no common fields on the report type

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, joined-reports

I have two report types:

Report type A: Contact Roles
Report type B: Sport Affiliations

They both share the Lookup field "Account".

But still I get this error:
"Choose a different report type. This one has no common fields with the other report types in this joined report."

[image]

Data model:

[image]

Comment: Block 1 (principal report) = Accounts report. Then add the other two reports as blocks 2 and 3. If all three blocks have Account ID as a field, it should work.

Comment: @identigral still not able. I added Accounts, Contacts, Contact Roles and when I tried to add Sports Affiliation object I get the same message. The Sports Affiliations also has a Lookup relationship to the Account (called School__c) and the Id field as a text formula Account__ID__c. So you think it has do be due to the naming of the Lookup relationship?

Comment: The naming doesn't matter, it's your custom report type. When you create a custom object with lookup, report types are automatically created. Try using those.